# How to implement a code button in a javascript wysiwyg editor

Tags: javascript

I try to build my own WYSIWYG editor in javascript.
Most of the buttons are quite simple (as long as document.execCommand has a commandId).

But how to implement a code option like in StackOverflow editor.

**What I tried:**

```
document.execCommand('formatBlock', '<pre><code>')
```

Unfortunately, it is not working. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `document.execCommand` is obsolete according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand. "[...] its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<code>` tag is not part of the list of supported tags for *formatBlock*. You can however insert a `<pre>` tag by using:

```js
document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<pre>');
```

You can check [the w3c documentation](https://w3c.github.io/editing/docs/execCommand/#the-formatblock-command) for a list of supported tags (it depends on the browser).

If you do not care about IE, you can use the `insertHTML` option, combined together with `document.getSelection()`, like so:

```js
document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, `<pre><code>${document.getSelection()}</code></pre>`)
```

Or you could implement the functionality yourself. As pointed out by others, `document.execCommand` [is now obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), so it might be your safest option, depending on which browsers you need to support.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Didn't noticed that. Looks like there is also no alternative yet right?

Comment: Actually if you do not care about IE there is a way to do it with `insertHTML` so I will update my answer.